# Automatically adding space before punctuation in old-style English texts

Tags: spacing, punctuation

I'm typesetting an English text in an 18th century style (based on a 1725 edition of Alexander Pope's "Dunciad"). Is there a LaTeX package I can use to automatically add the correct space before (and after) punctuation? I need something similar to the spacing given for "french" in babel, but there doesn't seem to be an option to do this for "english", and the closest I can find in another package is ecclesiastic.sty, which does a similar thing for Latin.

Comment: You probably need to explain what this entails more clearly.  Surprisingly, not everyone is familiar with the 1725 edition of the *Dunciad*.  Is it identical to what French typography requires, or only similar in certain respects?

Comment: LaTeX provides the `\frenchspacing` declaration, which turns off the (ugly) default habit of adding extra spacing _after_ fullstops. I'm not aware of other options. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Just from looking at a facsimile, I'm not sure what the rules are. I was hoping for guidance on that as well as technical suggestion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use a recent `pdflatex` you can also enable the french extrakerning of `microtype`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[kerning=true]{microtype}

\begin{document}
What is the result of these settings? 
Some space! 

\microtypecontext{kerning=french}
What is the result of these settings?
Some space!
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! Merely adding \usepackage{microtype} gets me basic optical alignment, and the manual explains how to customize the spacing of punctuation. I will start with the settings for French and try to find out what old-style English actually requires (and if I get a good answer, add it here).

Comment: @ReubenThomas - Be aware that (current) French typographic usage calls for (and `microtype`'s `kerning=french` setting thus implements) a slightly larger amount of whitespace before a colon (`:`) than before the other three symbols of interest. This may, or may not, be what your typesetting needs require.

Comment: Thanks @Mico, I have adapted the default French settings to make the spacing before each of ; : ! and ? the same, as that is what seems to be the case in the facsimile I'm working from (though there the extra space varies quite a bit).

Answer (score 15):

You could make the `!`, `?`, `;`, and `:` characters "active" in TeX jargon, i.e., turn them into control sequences which, in this case, automatically insert a "thinspace" *before* the corresponding characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`\!=\active \edef!{\unskip\noexpand\,\string!}
\catcode`\:=\active \edef:{\unskip\noexpand\,\string:}
\catcode`\;=\active \edef;{\unskip\noexpand\,\string;}
\catcode`\?=\active \edef?{\unskip\noexpand\,\string?}

\begin{document}
Hello? World! I'm; here: now.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Spaces are not ignored after active characters, so `\xspace` is not needed. I'd add instead `\unskip` before the thin space: copying from a source where the punctuation signs are spaced can lead to inserting spaces in the input. I'd write `\edef!{\unskip\noexpand\,\string!}`, so defining `\ExclaSign` is redundant, but it's a matter of taste. In any case a space before the closing brace in the definition of `\ExclaSign` is important.

Comment: Is there a functional solution that would also work for commas (i.e. without messing up all lists and multiple arguments)? I know there was some discussion of this a while ago… In some ancient texts, there is also a space before commas.

Comment: How to make it work for slashes (/)? The naive solution doesn't work.

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker - Please state what you mean by "the naive solution". For sure, copying the last line of the preamble and changing the three instances of `?` to `/` works just fine.

Comment: This doesn't go well with `\label{with:colon}`.

Comment: It doesn't apply to the other answer. And the question doesn't mention active characters.

Comment: @Toothrot - And the OP didn't mention `\label{with:colon}` -- or cross-referencing in general. What are you trying to get at?

Comment: That there is a problem with this solution. Same with tikz and semicolons.

Comment: @Toothrot -- please be less cryptic.

Comment: This will probably produce errors with tikz as well, which I think uses semicolons to end commands.

Comment: @Toothrot -- I made no claim that the proposed solution works with all packages under the sun. I made no claim that it works always and everywhere, regardless of the circumstances . I'm confident, though, that it's entirely adequate for the setup described by the OP.  I thus see no reason to make any changes. If you disagree, you are entirely free to provide a new answer, in which you can (and should) explain in which sense your solution is better than mine.

Comment: Why so antagonistic?  I pointed out a problem; I didn't blame you for it or demand that you fix it.

Comment: @Toothrot - "Why so antagonistic?" It's *you* who's being antagonistic, not me. You keep calling things "problems" even though, given the OP's setup, it's quite clear that they're not. It's been more than five years since I wrote the original answer; nobody else, not even the OP, appears to have felt strongly enough about this answer to point out the (non-existent, in my view) problems.