# Automatically adding space before punctuation in LuaLaTeX

Tags: spacing, luatex, punctuation, lua

I'm typesetting a text in which I want to add space before double punctuation using LuaLaTeX.

---

To give you the idea: Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64598/15659) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329386/15659), I wrote following code which do not work (for "Test!" it returns "Test0.1em!" and I did expect "Test !")

```
\def\dblpnct#1{\unskip\noexpand\hspace{0.1em}#1}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function dosub(s)
    s = string.gsub(s, '!', '\\dblpnct!')
    s = string.gsub(s, ':', '\\dblpnct:')
    s = string.gsub(s, ';', '\\dblpnct;')
    s = string.gsub(s, '?', '\\dblpnct?')
    return(s)
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \luaexec{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", dosub, "dosub")}%
}
```

Comment: Try removing \noexpand. Works for me.

Comment: your lua works but you have added  something equivalent to `\unskip\relax{0.1em}!` so it just typesets `0.1em`

Comment: @RobtA do you want to make the comment an answer?

Comment: French style spaces around colons obey different rules than semicolon, question mark and exclamation mark. Around the colon there should be normal interword spaces. Instead of `\noexpand` you should have `\nolinebreak`.

Comment: You should look at how `babel-frenchb` does it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\noexpand` is the culprit. But removing it is not the full answer.

There's no reason for defining `\dblpnct` with an argument, but this is not a real problem.

If you are implementing French style spacing before double punctuation, you should be aware that the colon obeys different rules: it should be preceded and followed by a normal interword space. But most important is that you don't want the added space is a feasible line break point.

Defensive code requires also that `\unskip` is only issued if we're in horizontal mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd\dblpnct[1]{%
  \ifhmode\unskip\fi
  \nolinebreak#1%
}
\begin{luacode}
function dosub(s)
    s = string.gsub(s, '!', '\\dblpnct{\\hspace{0.1em}}!')
    s = string.gsub(s, ':', '\\dblpnct{\\space}:')
    s = string.gsub(s, ';', '\\dblpnct{\\hspace{0.1em}};')
    s = string.gsub(s, '?', '\\dblpnct{\\hspace{0.1em}}?')
    return(s)
end
\end{luacode}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \luaexec{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", dosub, "dosub")}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text ! Or is it a question ? The colon : obeys different ; rules.

Some text! Or is it a question? The colon: obeys different; rules.

\end{document}
```

[image]

And you should also disable this in math mode, or the spacing will be definitely wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd\dblpnct[1]{%
  \ifmmode\else
    \ifhmode\unskip\fi
    \nolinebreak#1%
  \fi
}
\begin{luacode}
function dosub(s)
    s = string.gsub(s, '!', '\\dblpnct{\\hspace{0.1em}}!')
    s = string.gsub(s, ':', '\\dblpnct{\\space}:')
    s = string.gsub(s, ';', '\\dblpnct{\\hspace{0.1em}};')
    s = string.gsub(s, '?', '\\dblpnct{\\hspace{0.1em}}?')
    return(s)
end
\end{luacode}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \luaexec{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", dosub, "dosub")}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text ! Or is it a question ? The colon : obeys different ; rules.

Some text! Or is it a question? The colon: obeys different; rules.

Oh, what about math ? $a:b$ and $(a;b)$

\end{document}
```

Check the result if you remove the `\ifmmode` conditional.

[image]

In order to disable the behavior in the argument to `\label` and `\ref`, you can use `\ifincsname`, but this requires changing the definition of `\label`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd\dblpnct[1]{%
  \ifincsname
  \else
    \ifmmode\else
      \ifhmode\unskip\fi
      \nolinebreak#1%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatletter
% latex.ltx, line 4070:
\def\label#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{\let\dblpnct\@gobble}% <-- disable in \label
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}
\makeatother

\begin{luacode}
function dosub(s)
    s = string.gsub(s, '!', '\\dblpnct{\\hspace{0.1em}}!')
    s = string.gsub(s, ':', '\\dblpnct{\\space}:')
    s = string.gsub(s, ';', '\\dblpnct{\\hspace{0.1em}};')
    s = string.gsub(s, '?', '\\dblpnct{\\hspace{0.1em}}?')
    return(s)
end
\end{luacode}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \luaexec{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", dosub, "dosub")}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text ! Or is it a question ? The colon : obeys different ; rules.

Some text! Or is it a question? The colon: obeys different; rules.

Oh, what about math ? $a:b$ and $(a;b)$

Here's a reference to page~\pageref{page:x}\label{page:x}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid substitution taking place in labels? I have `\label{eq:test}` and it produces errors.

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker There should be; I'll check on it later.

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker I added how to cope with `\label` and `\ref`.

Comment: [related issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333590/15659)

Comment: [another related issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336297/15659)

Comment: ! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

Comment: @Toothrot You have to remove the callback when in a `tikzpicture`

Answer (score 3):

As I noted in a comment: Simply removing
    `\noexpand`
from the OP's code works.

Comment: Evidently there is a way to markup inline code, but I didn't see how. Care to enlighten me? If there is a link to the code, I didn't readily find it on the page. I had tried putting it on a separate line with spaces in front, but that didn't work.

Comment: Put backticks around it. If you just edit your post, you'll see how it is done for yourself.