# hyperref error : ! Argument of \@providesfile has an extra }

Tags: hyperref, luatex, lua

[Using a solution to adjust spacing in my document with LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333001/15659), I run into this cryptic error, as soon as I use `\label{}` in a math environment:

```
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-pdfdoc.def
! Argument of \@providesfile has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.51 ...dblpnct{\hspace{0.08334em}}: PDFDocEncoding]

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
{se-pdfdoc.def}{\@firstoftwo {\@hspacer }}\def \reserved@b {\@hspace \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@providesfile was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.51 ...dblpnct{\hspace{0.08334em}}: PDFDocEncoding]

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

File: se-pdfdoc.def 2016/05/16 v1.11 stringenc\dblpnct {\protect \let \reserved@
d =*\def \par }: PDFDocEncoding
! Argument of \@providesfile has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.51 ...dblpnct{\hspace{0.08334em}}: PDFDocEncoding]

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
{se-pdfdoc.def}{\@firstoftwo {\@hspacer }}\def \reserved@b {\@hspace \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@providesfile was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.51 ...dblpnct{\hspace{0.08334em}}: PDFDocEncoding]

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

) [1
Non-PDF special ignored!
```

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,pdfpagelabels=true,psdextra]{hyperref}   % PROBLEMATIC PACKAGE
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\dblpnct#1{}}   % TRIED TO FIX IT, BUT FAILED

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\dblpnct[1]{%
  \ifincsname\else
    \ifmmode\else
      \ifhmode
        \unskip
      \fi
      \nolinebreak#1%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatletter
% latex.ltx, line 4070:
\def\label#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{\let\dblpnct\@gobble}% <-- disable in \label
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}
\makeatother
\begin{luacode}
function dosub(s)
    s = string.gsub(s, ':', '\\dblpnct{\\hspace{0.08334em}}:')
    return(s)
end
\end{luacode}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \luaexec{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", dosub, "dosub")}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:test}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @cfr: doesn't work

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should move the `\hspace` from the gsub in the definition of `\dblpnct` so that you don't have to fight against the expansion of the `\hspace` too. Then you can use `\NR@sanitize@labelname` to sanitize the label name. I exagerated the inserted space to check if there are side effects.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,pdfpagelabels=true,psdextra]{hyperref}   % PROBLEMATIC PACKAGE
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\dblpnct#1{}}   % TRIED TO FIX IT, BUT FAILED
%
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\dblpnct[1]{%
  \ifincsname\else
    \ifmmode\else
      \ifhmode
        \unskip
      \fi
      \nolinebreak\hspace{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{luacode}
function dosub(s)
    s = string.gsub(s, ':', '\\dblpnct{1.08334em}:')
    return(s)
end
\end{luacode}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \luaexec{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", dosub, "dosub")}%
    \ifpatchable*\NR@sanitize@labelname
    {\pretocmd\NR@sanitize@labelname{\let\dblpnct\@gobble}{}{\failed}}
    {}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

a:b

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:test} 
\end{equation}

a:b \label{ref:blub} a:b \ref{eq:test} a:b

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using your solution, I get the name of the chapter inside labeled equations. MWE: `\begin{document}
\chapter{chap}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:test}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove the `\@onelevel@sanitize` when changing from `\patchcmd` to `\pretocmd`. I edited the code, it should work now.

Comment: [Related issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336297/15659)