# What is the difference between using `\edef` with `\noexpand` and simply `\def`?

Tags: plain-tex

In this question: [Automatically adding space before punctuation in old-style English texts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64591/automatically-adding-space-before-punctuation-in-old-style-english-texts), the accepted answer uses the following definition

```
\edef!{\unskip\noexpand\,\string!}
```

What is the difference with the apparently simpler

```
\def!{\thinspace\string!}
```

apart from the `\unskip` which I know is not needed if `!` is inputed correctly (i.e., without space before it).

Comment: Correct, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `\def!{\thinspace\string!}` the contents of `!` will be exactly that, so `\thinspace \string !13`, and when it's fully expanded upon usage, the `\string` will turn `!13` into `!12`.

On the other hand `\edef!{\unskip\noexpand\,\string!}` will contain `\unskip \,!12`, so `\string` will already have done its job, and the expansion of `!` can't possibly lead to another `!13`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, there are equivalent when used in a text but the one using `edef` "precompiles" the result while the one using `def` computes it on the fly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Laravel yes, one could say that (as well as the other subtle difference of `\unskip` and `\;` vs `\thinspace`).